# Facebook sharing not working

Tags: facebook-sharer, addthis

I'm getting an weird behavior while sharing my link on Facebook. But other services like Twitter, LinkedIn etc are working fine.[Here](http://www.maerskline.com/link/?page=news&path=/news/news20120217_dup) is the URL I'm trying to share .

Code used for sharing is from [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com/)

But when sharing, giving me scripting error

> "Your browser does not support scripting, or you have disabled that
>   feature. To get help, please send us a mail to receive a call back."

Can you please help me debugging what is the problem?

The url generated for sharing on Facebook is as follows...

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maerskline.com%2Flink%2F%3Fpage%3Dnews%26path%3D%252Fnews%252Fnews20120217_dup%23.UM8CF1OJGZA.facebook

Comment: You cannot pass any queryString variables or UTM codes via AddThis sharer along with the og:url. I explain the fix I used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23410463/1013405)

Answer (score 0):

facebook might have blocked this website in their entire structure.
To check if so, try to paste that maerskline.com link in any comment box. If the problem happens in commenting that link to any status update too, then you can use http://goo.gl/ to convert your maerskline.com link to some other innocent looking link that will fool the facebook and allow you to post that link anywhere in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a scripting error, it´s what´s right in your sourcecode. It is also not blocked, else there would be an error message saying so.

I suggest using Open Graph Tags, see here:

http://ogp.me/

After adding some of them (title, description, image, ...) everything will show up correctly. Test here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Take a look at the warnings, they tell you which Open Graph tags you should use as minimum. If you don´t include any Open Graph Tags, Facebook will use some text from your page. Unfortunately, the Facebook Linter does not know JavaScript, so it will grab the error message right from your page.

Comment: We investigated further on this at our end and it does not seem to be scripting error. This is related to https. 
What we conclude is that the page is delivered to Facebook but for some reason extracts Facebook only the content of the LiveHelp iFrame (withing the content) which states: "Your browser does not support scripting...". 
We have registered that the page Facebook fetches is returned from the server and there are no errors.
Can you help us to know why Facebook is fetching content from the <iframe> tag instead of whole HTML response?

Comment: of course it is not a scripting error, that´s what i wrote. did you try adding open graph tags, like i mentioned? if you add them, facebook will surely use the correct data.

Comment: No, we cannot do that because we run on portal. So to implement, it needed a major change.
We tried removing the <iframe> and we are able to post the content. But removing <iframe> would not be the solution as the portal needs that. It will be nice if you can tell us why Facebook is fetching content from the <iframe> tag instead of the whole HTML response?

Comment: facebook will fetch anything from the page, if there are no open graph tags. can´t you even put a meta description in? i mean, every page should have that...

Answer (score 0):

Promblem in end of uri `%23.UM8CF1OJGZA.facebook`. Have same error but other code (UZt1MuSm2WM not UM8CF1OJGZA)

Answer (score 0):

## What Worked For Me

For those who the above didn't work: 
If you happen to be trying to use AddThis with UTM codes or other querystring variables, here's what finally worked for me.

As per [Sol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852328/1013405), use  [OpenGraph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) but then use the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to verify that Facebook cache has been refreshed and got all the proper meta tags in the page header correctly, then verify that there are no querystring UTMs/variables your AddThis sharing link to facebook. For my purposes, Index.html couldn't include any querystring variables or AddThis passed the URL incorrectly to Facebook. The only way that worked for me looks like this:

```
<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/facebook/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.html" target="_blank" ><img src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/facebook.png" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

## What Failed For Me

When trying to use the below AddThis "data_track_addressbar" and "addthis_widget.js" modules for sharing, Facebook completely fail to pull the new OpenGraph Meta Tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```